# mod_security blocks data binding in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-8, mod-security, mod-security2

I've installed mod_security 2.7.5 successfully after a long time dealing with 2.9.0.

But now, I faced a problem.
I created an MVC project and deployed it to an IIS server with mod_security installed. I created a simple login page with MVC 4, and when I press login, username and password are not sent to my server. That's why my login function failed. The POST data is sent, but the model binding does not happen.

Here is my C# project

Can anyone help me please ? 
This isn't because of rules because I'm using the base rules of mod_security 2.7.5 and no error was logged in Event Viewer related to rules.

- mod_security : 2.7.5
- IIS : 8.0
- MVC 4
- Windows 7

Here is my project : https://www.dropbox.com/s/a196c2qgyruc20f/MVC4_ModSecurity.rar?dl=0

Thank you.